# algorithm for assignnig jobs to hosts based on remaining space

Tags: algorithm, resources, allocation

Input:

- The list of instances of jobs such that (job_i, size_of_job_i) where
  i = 1..n
- The list of hosts such that (host_j, remaining_space_host_j)
  where j = 1..m

Want

- assign jobs to hosts accordingly.

Output

- (host_j, job_i) where j=1..m and i = 1..n

FYI, as a job is assign to a host, the remaining space for a host will be decreasing. 
For example, after a job1 = (job_1, 1TB) is assigned to a host1 = (host_1, 100TB), host1 becomes (host_1, 90TB).

Currently, using Greedy algorithm and the way of Greedy algorithm works is finding a largest remaining host first and assign jobs to them.

The problem of this algorithm is the jobs are not distributed across all hosts. 
Which means some hosts which have sufficient remaining space don't have jobs and some hosts have too many jobs assigned.

I'm pretty sure there is some famous algorithm for this.
I googled with the keyword "resource allocation algorithm", but couldn't find a right one for me. Maybe I chose a wrong keyword.

Does anyone know or recommend a good simple algorithm for this?

Comment: It sounds like a variant of the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), where you would have to perform several rounds of assignment and update the host's loads accordingly until every job has been taken care of. By the way, I think you meant 99TB in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Knapsack problem may help you. Give it a look.

It is about items which have weight variables. Question is what is the best combination if backpack's limit is X(1,2,3...).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at a greedy solution which is a modification to your existing solution. 
To clearly understand my solution, let's understand it using an example.

Let's suppose we have 5 jobs in front of us:-

```
J1(1TB) , J2(5TB), J3(2TB), J4(3TB), J5(2TB).
```

And we have 3 Hosts as:-

```
H1(25TB), H2(8TB), H3(10TB).
```

Now Let's say the order in which Jobs arrive are from 1 to n, in our case `n=5`
i.e `J1, J2, J3, J4, J5`

```
1. For J1, we pick Host with highest capacity = H1. And we increase the job count on this host by 1.
2. For J2, we sort by job count and then by remaining space and we get order of hosts as - H3, H2, H1. And we assign J2 for H3.
```

After the above two iterations our Host details are something like this:-

```
H1(1, 24) , H2(0,8), H3(1,5).

3. Let's continue, for J3 - we pick H2
4. For J4, now all the three hosts have 1 job count, let's pick by remaining space i.e H1 takes up this job.
```

After the above two iterations our Host details are something like this:-

```
H1(2,21), H2(1,6), H3(1,5)

5. J5 goes to H2 because job count is lowest and remaining space is more.
```

So our final configuration will be

```
H1(2,21), H2(2,4), H3(1,5).
```

Now I am not saying this is perfectly efficient technique but we can see some level of load balancing happening here.

Hope this helps!